# How to save Firebase dataSnapshot object and key into Kotlin DTO data class?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, dto

The objective: Update Firebase realTime database from an Android device.

My data structure simplified:

[image]

My Data Class **TasksDTO.kt**:

```
data class TasksDTO(var customer : String ="", var date : String ="", var location : String ="", var key : String="") { 
   

}
```

I've added an `addValueEventListener` under `onCreate`:

```
 private var allTasks = ArrayList<TasksDTO>()//Used to update recyclerView. 
 reference.child("tasks").addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled...

    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val children = dataSnapshot.children
       
        allTasks.clear()

        children.forEach {

            var taskObj = it.getValue()//without key: it.getValue(TasksDTO::class.java)
            var task = TasksDTO()

            with(task){
                customer = taskObj.customer //**ERROR: Unresolved reference**
                date = taskObj.date //**ERROR: Unresolved reference**
                location = taskObj.location //**ERROR: Unresolved reference**
                key = it.key!!
            }

            //
            allTasks.add(task!!)

        }
        recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        

    }

}
```

I want to be able to update firebase data in the `onclick item listener` function of the recyclerView. To do that I need to have reference to the `key` to update the database. Unless there is a more efficient method. I'm open to correction.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: With the code you have right now, taskObj is going to be a Map with string keys and object values.  You need to use that map to pull the child values out.  It looks like you're assuming it's something else?

Comment: I assumed it to be an object based on this documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html#getValue--

Comment: Yes, and that object can be cast to a Map in this case, if the thing in the database has child values.  You can't simply start referencing properties on an object - the compiler has no idea if those things actually exist.  I suggest you start up a debugger to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A HashMap stores key, value pairs which can be referenced unlike an object from a database.

```
var taskObj = it.getValue() as HashMap<*, *>
                    var task = TasksDTO()

                    with(task){
                        customer = taskObj ["customer"].toString()
                        key = it.key.toString()
                        date = taskObj ["date"].toString()
                        location = taskObj ["location"].toString()
                    }
```

Credit goes to Doug Stevenson see OP's comments.

Answer (score 0):

To get the key, you should use `getKey()` method, for example:

```
taskObj = it.getKey()
```

Comment: That isn't the issue. Passing the value object together with the key value into the data class is the thing I don't know how to accomplish. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin 1.4.32

Make a kotlin class like this:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class TasksDTO(
    var customer: String? = "",
    var date: String? = "",
    var location: String? = ""
){
    constructor() : this("", "", "") {}
    @Exclude
    fun toMap(): Map<String, Any?> {
        return mapOf(
            "customer" to customer,
            "date" to date,
            "location" to location
        )
    }
}
```

When you have your `DataSnapshot` obtained as response (suppose called `it`) from Firebase database calls, you can  do something like this:

```
var snap = (it as DataSnapshot)
var myTasksDTO = snap.getValue(TasksDTO::class.java)
```